# debugger doesn't work in chrome / safari/ firefox for ember app

Tags: debugging, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools, ember-cli

I am working in an ember application. The version is "ember-cli": "1.13.13".

For a very strange reason, debugger doesn't work in Chrome. (I also tried Safari, and Firefox developer's edition. Same thing.)

Specifically, the problem is I put a debugger statement in a function. Ember app loads and hits the function and the debugger statement in the function. What happens in the Developer Tools -> Sources tab is that it doesn't show me the function that the debugger is in.

Instead it keeps highlighting the last line of `app-boot.js` file. The breakpoint, or the line that it's paused on, is not showing up at all. (see screenshot attached)

Furthermore when I step into the function call using the down arrow, it remains at `app-boot.js`, so I have no idea whether it did step into the function or not.

This has been plaguing me for a while now.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: Turns out, our issue was that we had added ember-cli-pace to our app so we could get a progressive loading bar, and that screwed up the sourcemaps.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved many times similar error on OSX + Chrome by using **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** - after that code in Sources tab was updated and I could correctly see actual source code.

Make sure you didn't blackbox scripts of your application.

Alternatively you could try to reinstall npm packages, bower packages - it might be issue with creating source maps in Ember CLI.

If nothing helps please investigate your JavaScript and associated map files and check if something might be missing, or maps don't update. You could possibly try turning them on and off in Ember CLI.

See [Source Maps](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#source-maps) section in Ember CLI guides how to enable/disable them.